# Cost of adding and empty attribute to an object in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I was going through leetcode and working on the problem of detecting the start of a cycle in a linked list.
There is a 2 pointer approach that goes through the list once to detect a loop and then detects the size of that loop and then does one more pass to find the start.

I thought maybe i could use the graph approach of marking a node as visited and detect the starting point in one pass and use another pass to get rid of the marker. The marker here being adding an attribute to an object and pointing it to none and checking for the presence of that attribute, using `hasattr()`,  to detect start of cycle.

I tried using `sys.getsizeof()` to determine the memory cost and it didn't show a difference before adding the attribute and after.

The question here being, is the second approach better in python than the first one? Theorotically it seems like I'm using more space - but can an empty attribute be ignored practically?

Comment: Attributes are entries in a dictionary, which is a hash table. A hash table takes up a fixed amount of space until it reaches a threshold, then it grows. So adding 1 attribute does't use up more space by itself, but eventually it will add up.

Comment: @Barmar do you know the expansion criteria for a dict in python?

Comment: https://lerner.co.il/2019/05/12/python-dicts-and-memory-usage/